# Not being able to capture anonymous type result return from SqlQuery execution EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, anonymous-types

i try to execute this code. i got no error but could not get desired result. see my code

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new TestDBContext1())
    {
    var customers = await db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("AllCustomers").ToListAsync();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;
    }
}
```

when i try to debug the customer then found no customer data in it but right result count was showing. when bind customer to `datagridview` then no result shown.

just do not understand why dynamic is not working here ?

i need something which store customer data to customers variable and i should query customers variable and should be able to bind customers variable to grid.help me with knowledge.

thanks

Comment: `dynamic` simply doesn't work. Take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx): *The type can be any type that **has properties** that match the names of the columns returned from the query*

Comment: if possible post a sample code to overcome this situation where i do not have to specify class name inside SqlQuery() function.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible. Create a class with the properties matching the result of the query and specify that type.